# When is the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ an epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For every ring $R$ there exists a unique ring homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z} \to R$.  For which rings is this an epimorphism?

The only examples I know are the subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the quotient rings of $\mathbb{Z}$, namely the rings $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n \rangle$.  Are these all, or are there more?

Three characterizations of epimorphisms of *commutative* rings are listed here:

- [Epimorphisms of rings](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM), The Stacks Project.

Maybe one will help.

(Why I'm interested: an object in a category is **subterminal** if its unique morphism to the terminal object is a monomorphism.  Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in $\mathrm{Ring}$, here I am asking what are the subterminal objects in $\mathrm{Ring}^{\rm op}$.)

Comment: One thing you can say right away is that the regular epimorphisms arise as the surejections and are all isomorphic to rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. For the non-regular epimorphisms I'm not entirely sure, but I think there's a localization trick you could do to reduce it to the case of subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ inverting various sets of (non-zero) integers. I'll play around with the second idea today and tomorrow and see if I can get anywhere helpful.

Comment: The map is an epimorphism if and only if the dominion of $f(\mathbb{Z})$ in $R$ is $R$. The dominion in rings is described by the Isbell-Silver-Mazet  ZigZag Lemma: given a subring $B$ or $R$, the dominion of $B$ is precisely the elements that can be written as $XYZ$, where $X$ is a row, $Y$ is a matrix, and $Z$ is a column over $R$, such that  $XY$ and $YZ$ have entries in $B$. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like/139#139) and references therein.

Comment: In fact, the [answer by Torsten Schoenberg](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like/110443#110443) seems to directly address the question "What do epimorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ look like?" and gives references, though I think they only concern commutative $B$s.

Comment: Thanks!   Schoenberg cites Bousfeld and Kan's https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404972900230, which apparently completely settles the question for *commutative* rings.  TL;DR: there are lots more examples than the ones I listed, but in some sense the commutative ones are all built up from those examples.

Comment: Every epimorphic image of a commutative ring is commutative, according to Prop. 1.3 (b) of H.H. Storrer's *Epimorphic extensions of non-commutative rings*. Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici 48, 72–86 (1973). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02566112

Comment: I should have realized that the epimorphic image of a commutative ring is commutative. It is a basic result of dominions in semigroups and groups and the centralizer of a substructure is the centralizer of its dominion, and in particular that an abelian substructure has an abelian dominion, so it is not a surprise that the same holds for rings.

Answer (score 9):

Let me summarize what I've learned from the comments.  A ring $R$ for which the unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$ is an epimorphism is called a **solid** ring.  Such rings are necessarily commutative, by Prop. 1.3 (b) of this paper:

- H. H. Storrer, [Epimorphic extensions of non-commutative rings](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN358147735_0048?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B76%5D,%22view%22:%22thumbnails%22%7D), *Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici* **48** (1973), 72–86.

By [well-known results](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM) in commutative ring theory, a solid ring is thus the same as any of these:

- a commutative ring $R$ for which the multiplication map $m \colon R \otimes R \to R$ is an isomorphism;
- a commutative ring $R$ such that the forgetful functor $R\, \mathsf{Mod} \to \mathsf{AbGp}$ is full.
- a commutative ring whose **core** $ cR = \{r \in R: r \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes r \in R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R \} $ is all of $R$.

Commutative solid rings, and thus all solid rings, were classified here:

- A. K. Bousfield and D. M. Kan, [The core of a ring](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404972900230), *Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* **2** (1972), 73–81.

The following rings are solid:

1. $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for any $n$.
2. any subring $R \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.   Such a subring is always of the form $\mathbb{Z}[P^{-1}]$, meaning the ring of fractions whose denominators (in lowest terms) are divisible only by the primes in some set $P$ of primes.
3. any ring of the form $\mathbb{Z}[P^{-1}] \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ where each prime factor of $n$ is in $P$.

Bousfeld and Kan show that in the category of commutative rings, every colimit of solid rings is solid.   They also show that every solid ring is a colimit, in the category of commutative rings, of solid rings of the above three types.

Bousfeld and Kan also give a more explicit description of all the solid rings.  They show that every solid ring is either of types 1-3 or of a fourth type:

4. $c(\mathbb{Z}[P^{-1}] \times \prod_{p \in Q} \mathbb{Z}/p^{e(p)}) $, where $P$ and $Q$ are infinite sets of primes with $Q \subseteq P$ and each $e(p)$ is a positive integer.   (Here $c$ stands for the core, as defined above.)

Comment: You can access the paper by Storr from the link appearing here https://eudml.org/doc/139538

Comment: I think another characterization would be that a ring $R$ is solid iff for any other ring $S$, there is at most one morphism $R \to S$ (this is easily seen to be equivalent to the characterization of $R$ being equal to its own core, the core being the equalizer of all possible morphisms out of $R$)