# There is a set of solid rings; is there also a set of epimorphisms $R→A$ for $R$ fixed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra

All rings here are commutative. A ring $R$ is called *solid* if the unique morphism $ℤ→R$ is an epimorphism. For instance, $ℤ/nℤ$ for $n∈ℕ$, or $ℚ$, or even $ℤ/nℤ × ℚ$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251193/when-is-the-ring-homomorphism-mathbbz-to-r-an-epimorphism/4251470#4251470).

In the comments of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432714/quotient-objects-of-a-commutative-ring) was raised the question of whether the class of epimorphisms $R→A$, for a fixed ring $R$, is a set (modulo isomorphism). This is true for $R=ℤ$. Is it true for any commutative ring?

Intuitively, I would have said it's not true there is a set of solid rings because in [Isbell's zigzag lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like/139#139), I would have thought we can make the criterion "go to infinity" somehow and construct arbitrarily large solid rings. So I find this surprising, and would like to know about the general case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79761) and the sources that it links to, if $R\to A$ is a commutative ring epimorphism then the cardinality of $A$ is at most that of $R$, from which it easily follows that for a given commutative ring $R$ there is only a set of (isomorphism classes of) ring epimorphisms $R\to A$.

Comment: Thank you very much! More specifically, this is proved at the end of the French text [Caractérisation des épimorphismes par relations et générateurs](http://www.numdam.org/item/SAC_1967-1968__2__A2_0.pdf) by Mazet. It explains why what I said in the third paragraph of my question doesn't work.