# What is the set $S$ of rings $R$ such that, for all rings $R'$, there is at most one nonzero homomorphism $R \to R'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

> What is the set $S$ of rings $R$ such that, for all rings $R'$, there is at most one nonzero homomorphism $R \to R'$?

We're dealing only with commutative rings with unity, and our definition of ring homomorphisms require $1_R \mapsto 1_{R'}$, and we're excluding considering the zero homomorphism. We know $\mathbb Z \in S$ and also $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \in S$, which leads us to posit that any element of $S$ will have some special property $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ have that makes them have a unique homomorphism, if it exists. After some thinking, I've come up with the possible hypothesis that the special property is the following: $R \in S$ if and only if any $r \in R$ is a finite sum of $1_R$, which will imply membership of $S$ by virtue of the property of ring homomorphisms forcing $1_R \mapsto 1_{R'}$.

It turns out that all such rings are indeed members of $S$, but I'm uncertain whether the converse holds.

Any tips, hints, or thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts: 1) is it a problem you are allowing the zero homomorphism into $R'$ from every ring?  2) Most people read "given an arbitrary ring R' " as "for all rings $R'$". Is that what you meant?  Or did you just mean to consider when $Hom(R,R')$ is very simple for two particular fixed rings $R,R'$ in the category of rings?  Otherwise question 1) becomes important again when you hit $R'=R$.  If you allow the zero homomorphism and are quantifying over all rings, then nothing except the zero ring itself works.

Comment: $R = \mathbb{Q}$ is an example of a ring satisfying this property, but which does not satisfy the hypothesis that every element is a finite sum of $1_R$.  (Also, how do you count $\mathbb{Z}$ as satisfying your alternate property?)

Comment: @rschwieb thanks a lot for commenting; unfortunately I haven't done category theory yet so I can't exactly parse your phrasing, but (1) yes this turns out to be a problem, I'll modify the question accordingly, and (2) yes I understand "given an arbitrary ring R'" as you say. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks for your comment! I'll check $\mathbb Q$, the counterexample is much appreciated. For $\mathbb Z$, if I understood your question correctly, we have $z \in \mathbb Z$ has $z = z\cdot 1 = 1 + \cdots + 1$ a total of $z$ times

Comment: But what if $z$ is negative?

Comment: @DanielSchepler hm... you're right. We have $-1 - \cdots - 1$ a total of $z$ times but this is not the same as the general property I've stated. I will rethink this a bit, your thoughts are much appreciated

Comment: A trivial remark is that $R$ has this property if and only if every subring of $R$ has this property. So by Daniel Schepler's comment any subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ has this property

Comment: How do we know $\Bbb Q$ has this property?

Comment: The rings in this set have only one ring automorphism, the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $l,r:R\to R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R$ be the ring homomorphisms given by $l(x)=x\otimes 1$ and
$r(x)=1\otimes x$ for $x\in R$.

Suppose that there are two homomorphisms $\alpha,\beta:R\to R'$ for some $R'$. Then defining $\gamma:R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\to R'$ by $\gamma(x\otimes y)=\alpha(x)\beta(y)$, we get $\gamma\circ l=\alpha$ and $\gamma\circ r=\beta$, so if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distinct, then so are $l$ and $r$.

So the property asked for is equivalent to $l$ being equal to $r$.

This is one of many well-known properties equivalent to the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ being a [ring epimorphism](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM) (an epimorphism in the category of rings, which is not the same thing as a surjective ring homomorphism).

Rings $R$ for which $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ is a ring epimorphism have been called solid rings, and were classified by Bousfield and Kan. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251193/when-is-the-ring-homomorphism-mathbbz-to-r-an-epimorphism) for more details and references, but some examples of solid rings include

- $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n$,
- any subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, such subrings being of the form $\mathbb{Z}[P^{-1}]$, the rationals whose denominator is only divisible by primes in $P$, for $P$ any set of primes,
- $\mathbb{Z}[P^{-1}]\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where all the prime factors of $n$ are in the set $P$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!